# Display math expression in Dash Datatable

Tags: markdown, plotly-dash

I'm using a Datatable in my Dash app and would like to show a mathematical expression in the tooltip to explain how a value is calculated.
Since the tooltip text is displayed as markdown, I expected to just use `$` around the mathematical expression but this doesn't seem to work
Here is a simple example:

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

df = pd.DataFrame(OrderedDict([("x", [1, 2, 3]), ("x square", ["1", "4", "9"])]))

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],
    tooltip_data=[{'x': {'value': 'This is the x value', 'type': 'markdown'},
                   'x square': {'value': 'This is the y value, it is caluclated as $y = x^2$', 'type': 'markdown'}}]*3,
)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This gives the following result instead of the expected `x²`.
[image]

Is there a way to display math in a well-formatted way into these table tooltips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this question on the Plotly community forum: https://community.plotly.com/t/display-math-expressions-in-datatable-tooltips/68133/3.

There Plotly's community manager Adam Schroeder responded that it is currently only possible to use mathjax in `dcc.Graph` and in `dcc.Markdown` but not in DataTable.

So currently no solution to this problem.